# Is it possible to compare 2 groups while controlling for something?

Tags: group-differences, ancova, controlling-for-a-variable

Is it possible to compare two groups (e.g., t-test, Wilcoxon, Mann-Whitney test, etc.) while controlling for something?

E.g., I want to compare home ownership between military veterans and non-veterans, while controlling for educational attainment.

I can easily compare home ownership between military veterans and non-veterans (e.g. using the Wilcox test). But how can I do the same while controlling for educational attainment?

I think an ANCOVA does this, yes?

Comment: Use linear regression?

Comment: @Repmat Ah -- you're right... just have military status and education as independent variables, and the beta coefficient for each independent variable will automatically control for the other independent variable. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you have a large enough sample size, you can subset the data by educational attainment, and then compare vets vs. non-vets.

*Example:*

1) no HS: vets vs. non-vets

2) HS only: vets vs. non-vets

3) some college: vets vs. non-vets

.

.

.

Comment: Thanks! How about ANCOVA -- would that be okay too?

Comment: I think the way I described is simpler and easier to interpret... no need to overcomplicate :)